# Ruby open-uri throws an Bad uri error when I try to get a URL through user input. Why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri, open-uri

This code works fine when I provide URL directly into the script.

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

get_url = "http://google.com"

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(get_url))
puts doc
```

I tried entering "http://google.com" in user input but this doesn't work and throws a Bad uri error and says

> No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

get_url = gets

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(get_url))
puts doc
```

**Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong? I tries looking on google too but no straight answers.**

Comment: I'm not certain, but I think it's likely this happens to prevent XSS attacks. It's very risky to get a URL from user input - you could look at methods for sanitising this, but what you're doing looks very risky to me.

Comment: Should I try verifying it using Regex before reaching open(get_url)?

Comment: Is it because you need to use `gets.chomp`? There will be a trailing newline in your current code sample.

Comment: DO NOT pass user input directly into `open`. It can also execute system commands if the input is wrapped in back ticks. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=djaInGGBVFQ

Comment: Thank you for mentioning this @Drenmi :) However, I'm aware of this fact that it runs Kernel.open and could execute commands...I won't use it in open :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gets` adds a new line character to the end of the string. I have used `chomp` on the gets to remove this below.

It should work now

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

get_url = gets.chomp

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(get_url))
puts doc
```